# Is there a simple way to create a database?

Tags: javascript, database, save, persistent-storage

I have 5 multidimensional arrays, with each element having 2 properties. For example:

```
var arr = [week: 1, weektimes: [“mon01,tue01”]];
```

How would I save that (persistently, not locally), in the most simple manner? It should be when they hit the save button, then I need to retrieve it when they re-open the site.

I get this is a big question, so if you just want to direct me to additional resources, that’d be great. Thanks.

Comment: Lots of resources found easily on the web for remote data storage. Questions like this asking for resource recommendations are off topic on SO as outlined in the [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using firebase to save my database. I'm using the real time database and just have to do an Http request to get or post data.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

I'm using the free plan.